# How to reduce splash screen time in ionic 3?

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

Ionic app splash screen taking more time, to reduce its time as much as possible how can we do it.

Answer (score 2):

try Updating seconds value in config.xml file(default is 3000 you can reduce it if you don't want splash screen you can put the value as 0)

```
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="1000" />
```

reference link.
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/